# Key Press Event tunneling

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following hierarchy in WPF:

Window > Grid > ScrollViewer > StackPanel > [UserControl1, UserControl2 ...]

Now I would like to receive key press events in StackPanel as soon as the window is in focus. How do I accomplish this? Merely, adding code to PreviewKeyUp/Down handlers in StackPanel doesn't seem to work; looks like these events aren't tunneled from the Window through the StackPanel.

Should I be looking at RoutedEventHandlers?

Edit: What I noticed was, that the key events are received if the stack panel has focus. Otherwise, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Control), System.Windows.Controls.Control.KeyDownEvent, yourdelegate);
```

add it to application startup.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the event is not handled.

for example if you have:

```
 <Grid KeyDown="Grid_KeyDown">
    <ScrollViewer  Name="scrollViewer1" >
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1" >
            <TextBox Height="23" Name="textBox1" KeyDown="textBox1_KeyDown" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Note that the textbox event fired first. And then the other event fires.

If I place

```
e.Handled = true;
```

inside the method textBox1_KeyDown then the event will not buble meaning the method `Grid_KeyDown` will not execute.

The preview keword works the other way around. Instead of the event to bubble out like on the example I just show it will tunnel.

Try to make sure that the event is not being handled. Maybe the user control handles it.

Comment: What I noticed was, that the key events are received if the stack panel has focus. Otherwise, it doesn't.

Comment: Why do you need this functionality? what are you trying to accomplish? what will happen if you perform the action that you want to do in the event that always fires?

Comment: I want to display an overlay on *all* (focused or not) the UserControls when a key (say LeftCtrl) is pressed in the window. Right now, I am manually propogating the events from the Window to StackPanel to the UserControl by querying the children.